# CloudKit: Zone was purged by the user

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

One of my users deleted their cloud data, and now they are getting a "Zone was purged by the user" message. I believe it is returning error CKErrorUserDeletedZone, when fetching the zone.

The documentation states the following:

> - The user deleted this zone through the settings UI. Your client should either remove its local data or prompt the user before
>     attempting to re-upload any data to this zone. */

It is not clear whether I should delete the zone and create it again.
Has anyone gone through this situation ?.

Comment: Does this settings UI even exist yet? Just wondering because personally I haven't seen it. CloudKit enabled apps don't even appear in the iCloud Storage list.

Comment: In Mac go to your System Preferences -> iCloud -> Manage -> Select App -> Delete Documents & Data

Comment: Don't see CloudKit storage in there, only apps using iCloud documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zone was already deleted, you should ask the user if he want to recreate the database (if is possible) or stop using CloudKit.
If your app required CK, then you should ask the user to don't do it again.

Comment: how can a user actually delete the database? How could an app recreate the database and under what circumstances could this not be possible? And by database, do you actually mean CKRecordZone?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. Yes, I mean CKRecordZone. The user can delete his private record zones, but only the private, not the public. And you can only recreate the structure, not the data, unless you have a backup in other place.

Comment: @Joel How does a user delete their own private record zones from outside of the app?

Comment: @maddy users can delete all their iCloud data for any app from Settings -> iCloud -> Manage Storage.