# CloudKit Error "User Deleted Zone" (28/2042)

Tags: ios, macos, cloudkit

In my app, one of my users is no longer able to access the application iCloud container. The log file contains these errors:

```
<CKError <redacted>: "User Deleted Zone" (28/2042); 
server message = "Zone was purged by user"; 
uuid = <redacted>; container ID = "iCloud.<redacted>">
```

- Has anyone an idea on what the user may have done to unlink the app from his iCloud storage?
- How should I react within my application to this error to get it "back on track"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287815/cloudkit-zone-was-purged-by-the-user

Answer (score 4):

- This error is triggered when the user deletes your application data from Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage. You will not be able to test this in the Development environment, you need to debug in Production. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33432068/138820
- To get back on track, you just need to save the zone. If you keep server change tokens from fetches, you have to delete that as well, or you’ll keep getting the error when fetching

Comment: This second bullet point was extremely helpful! I had already recreated the zone, but was getting this error when I fetched records. Turns out my token was from the old zone. Thank you!